# Designing for Firefox ( / accomodating for its bugs)

Tags: best-practices, firefox, bugs

I am a (reasonably) new web developer.  As I've been getting more into testing / bug finding, I keep finding things that don't work on Firefox, exclusively.  Often, when I've found a solution to one of my problems on SE, I find there's some sort of caveat or exception made for Firefox.  In my GitHub (for a personal project), a fair fraction of problems (currently a majority) are tied to how Firefox renders the pages / elements.

E.g.

- images not being displayed (when they do on other browsers)
- Bootstrap grid items behaving differently
- textareas sizing differently
- etc...

My questions are:

1. **How far down the rabbit hole should I go in fixing these things?**  There's only so much time I have, and if the fraction of people using Firefox is negligible, it's not worth my time.
2. **Should I** /  (How do I) **report these things to Mozilla as bugs?**

Comment: To be perfectly blunt--cause your question is off topic here--the problem is going to be you. You are listing far too many problems to even begin to think it's Firefox. So I would bet three things: 1) You design everything in Chrome and then test in Firefox and/or 2) You don't validate your markup and/or 3) you aren't using a doctype. Or two or more of the three. But it's all guess work without any code. Firefox is an excellent browser overall used by hundreds of millions around the world.

Comment: @Rob I'm mostly self taught; your points 1 and 2 are fair. I am now trying to learn about validation. As for code, maybe I've been asking on the wrong part of SE.  Here's a question I've asked (with pseudo code) that I haven't gotten a response on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484006/django-bootstrap-rendering-differently-on-chrome-edge-vs-firefox

Comment: I can't help you with that. When you ask a question on SO, you need to show the generated markup and not the django stuff. It needs to be reproducible by anyone that reads the question. That's why you won't get an answer and why it should have been closed. I'm surprised it slipped through the cracks.

Comment: "How far down the rabbit hole should I go" is just asking for opinions.  I've worked for a site that supported any browser with at least 1% market share, but I've also worked with a site that only supported the top browser.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox works quite fine in my experience, however, sometimes it can be overzealous in it's markup. So what you are describing as something that doesn't work, may most probably be not an error on the browser, but on the page html that other browsers (i.e. Chrome) ignore, or compensate on behalf of the programmer.

Bootstrap / textareas, etc sizing issues can usually be fixed quite easily for most browsers with a **reset css**. There are many out there you can choose from. They work for Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc, so that the visual experience is more similar between them. (**Bootstrap** for example advocates the use of **reboot.css**, which is built by them.)

If you feel you've genuinely found an actual bug, do try to report it so that someone can look at your specific issue and triage it for a fix.

As per usage, it depends on a number of things like the countries your visitors are coming from, the type of content, etc. If you want global usage to be your guide, **Net Marketshare browser usage** reports puts Firefox usage at around 9% for desktop, 1% mobile for an average usage of 4%. (Information valid for May 2019).

Source: https://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx